# MFC: Choosing between a Dialog Based vs SDI vs MDI

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have following requirement for my MFC application:

```
Dialog 1 --> Dialog 2 --> Dialog 3 --> Dialog 4 -->  Dialog 5
    ^           |             |             ^           ^  |
    |           ----------------------------            |  |
    |                         |                         |  |
    |                         --------------------------   | 
    --------------------------------------------------------
```

- Navigate from Dlg1 to Dlg2 to Dlg3 to Dlg4 to Dlg5
- Navigate from Dlg2 to Dlg4
- Navigate from Dlg3 to Dlg5
- Navigate from Dlg5 back to Dlg1
- After navigation e.g. Dlg1 to Dlg2, the prevous dialog (Dlg1) shall **not be visible**
- The user shall not see that it is a different dialog when he navigates (E.g. from Dlg1 to Dlg2), he should have the feeling of one application.

Question: What application type should I use? (SDI, MDI, Dialog based)

Comment: This sounds like a standard CPropertySheet wizard with custom navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating SDI application then delete all document and view classes. Only CFrameWnd and CWinApp classes would stay. Make CFrameWnd non-resizable and dynamically Create all child dialogs into it. Then you would have one window CFrameWnd with many dynamically loading Dialogs inside.

Comment: This sound interesting. Could you add a code example how to "dynamically Create all child dialogs into it"? Thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_5E4_MNQcdMzJHbllJbHBESzQ/edit?usp=sharing. In example dialogs are loading from Ribbon but in your case you can remove Ribbon and status bar and call CMainFrame::OpenDialog() from wherever you want.

Comment: I finally made your example working for me in VS 2005. I will continue with your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about a tabbed dialog? Start with the dialog based architecture but replace the main dialog with a CPropertySheet. Your dialog 1 through dialog 5 will become pages in the tabbed sheet.

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but my requirement is more complex than described above. At the end I will have 100 different "dialogs", I wonder if i can manage this in tabs?

Comment: You sure can, and you can even create and insert tabs into the control as necessary (i.e. no need to create `Dialog79` page until the user has clicked on `Next` in `Dialog78`) and you can destroy old pages too.

Comment: You can also use CPropertySheet to implement a "Wizard" type user interface.  Does your app model a Wizard type application (i.e. the diagram you have drawn can be expanded to include the main flow of your UI).  Note that you can have "secondary" buttons on your "primary flow" dialogs to launch modal dialogs for performing "secondary" configuration functions.

Answer (score 0):

Choose either SDI or MDI. Many time initial requirements like yours make SDI the best fit but often times people have to convert SDI to MDI at the end of the road so use own your judgement if you might want to start MDI right away but given your today requirements SDI is good option.

You could also achieve the same with Dialog and use DoModal() but it will be a new window everytime. I in fact did this myself because I had to use CDialog and here is how I did it:

```
// here how I exit from say a given dialog to a different screen.
void CSummaryDlg::OnBnClickedButtonBack()
{
    EndDialog( Batch::BatchGoBack ); // goes to previous dialog
}


void CSummaryDlg::OnBnClickedButtonExitBatch()
{
    EndDialog( Batch::BatchComplete ); // finishes all dialogs in the chain.
}

// how ending all dialog takes places (example of propagation)
void CResultDlg::OnBnClickedButtonViewReport()
{
    CSummaryDlg dlg;

    int dlgResult = dlg.DoModal();

    if ( dlgResult == Batch::BatchComplete )
        EndDialog( Batch::BatchComplete );
}
```

Comment: Thanks zadane for your info. In case I create a SDI application, can I load a "normal" dialog which I created in the VS resource-view into the view part of the SDI application. Robert Valeika mentioned something (see below).

Comment: @Nextremos you will have CFormViews instead of CDialog and you can dynamically switch based on your need. You will have to implement the switching of window yourself..there is code out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dialog based application with an empty dialog, then dynamically insert the required dialog as a new window that fills the entire client area of the outer dialog. Set the [`DS_CONTROL` style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172(v=vs.85).aspx) of the inner dialogs. As you switch from one dialog to another, you can destroy the old one or just hide it for faster activation if you'll need it back again later.

Comment: Before asking this forum I tried exactly what you proposed. I had problems closing the initial (first dialog) when I've done this, the application exit. I tried to use ShowWindow by creating the dialogs dynamically but I failed.
If I unterstand you right, you would keep the initial empty dialog and dynamically replace always the 2nd (visible) dialog?

Comment: @Nextremos I think you have it - the outer dialog stays open all the time until the user exits, but the inner dialog gets replaced as necessary.